# Trying retrieve an unknown number of items in a list

Tags: python

I need to retrieve a list of objects from a cloud API. The list could be very short or very long.  If there are more than a 100 items in the list returned, a paging header is sent in the response as a reference point to send on the following request.

I've been trying to write a loop that would cover this, but the code is not reliable or very efficient:

```
paging=''
objects=cloud.list_objects()
try:
    paging=objects.headers['next-page']
except KeyError:
    pass
while len(paging)>0:
    objects=cloud.list_objects(page=paging)
    try:
        paging=objects.headers['next-page']
    except KeyError:
        paging=''
else:
     pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
paging = ''
while True:
    objects = cloud.list_objects(page=paging)
    paging = objects.headers.get('next-page')
    if not paging:
        break
```

Comment: Excellent. This is far more elegant too.